# For loop recursively create missing folder endlessly

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that will go through all the folders recursively in the current folder and create the folder "MP3" if it does not exist.

It is almost working but the problem is that when the code creates the "MP3" folder it will go in it and create another "MP3" folder then another and so on.  I don't know how to stop that behaviour.

Here is my code:

```
echo off
for /d /r %%i in (*) do (
    echo %%i
    if not exist "%%i\MP3\NUL" md "%%i\MP3"
)
PAUSE
```

Example of result:

Original folder structure.  The batch file is in "level0" folder

[image: folder structure]

Final folder structure.  The only thing stopping this code is when the path is too long! (not every level of "MP3" folder is shown)

[image]

I need the '/r' switch as I need to go through folders recursively but I did not expect it to enter the folder I have just created.

Is there a way to stop that behavior while still using the '/r' switch or do I have to let go the '/r' switch and code my own recursive function?

Comment: Do the list first. Stop doing `if exists`, there is no point as you want the directory to be there - so make it. Do tests wastes battery power and is twice as slow. `For /f "delims=" %A in ('dir "%userprofile%\desktop" /ad /b /s') Do echo md %~dpnxA\mp3`

Comment: @Mark, but what if the script is executed twice? I'd implement `if /I not "%%~nxA"=="mp3" ...`; and you should remove the root directory specification from `dir` since the `for` variable expansion (`~dp`) won't see it (hence you should to change to the root in advance)...

Comment: One line instead of many.

Comment: @aschipfl I took your suggestion with the 'if /I not...' except it's a folder therefore it's '%%~nA' and then went with the 'if not exist'.  Thanks

Comment: @Mark nice solution too, at first it did not work but it was just because of the 'echo' before the 'md' command.  I'll check which one will best fit in my project.  Thanks

Comment: That is so it doesn't trash your disk until you are ready to run it.

Comment: A folder can also have an extension, so `~nx` ensures the full name is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks for your help in the comments guys, this is my final project.

I figured it could help someone else so here it is.

Briefly, it goes through all my music folders and encode all my flac files to mp3 files into a MP3 folder located inside the flac files source folder using freac.

```
echo off
set freacpath="%programfiles(x86)%\freac\freaccmd.exe"

rem going through folders with recursion and then through all flac files
rem to convert to mp3 using freac LAME vbr quality 0 (best)
for /d /r %%i in (*) do (

rem check if the current folder is already named "mp3"
rem prior creating the mp3 folder
    if /I not "%%~ni" == "mp3" (
        if not exist "%%i\MP3\NUL" md "%%i\MP3"
    )

rem echo %%~ni
    for %%j in ("%%i"\*) do (
rem     echo %%~nj
        IF "%%~xj" == ".flac" (
            %freacpath% -e LAME -m VBR -q 0 -o "%%i\mp3\%%~nj".mp3 "%%j"
        )       
    )
)
PAUSE
```

The code is located in the music root directory.

Comment: Now remember to come back and mark it as the answer or no one will really see it again.